# How To Get Multi-Part Form Data Boundary Type

Tags: httpwebrequest, http-post, content-type, boundary, postdata

I am posting data to a website & need to generate the boundary. When I post manually the boundary is like this:

## 1 - 23281168279961

## 2 - 491299511942

## 3 - 4827543632391

(In order of time that I posted).

How is such a boundary generated?

Answer (score 0):

The boundary could be randomly generated. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html for discussion on what boundary is constituted of and [Generating multipart boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071257/generating-multipart-boundary) for it's sample implementation in Java.